# Javascript var change when reload page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a string array in javascript. But when I use href='mypage.php?id=var', I lost this array. I need keep it out for use it in the $_GET. This is the code:

```
<script>

var element_selected=[];
var i = 0;

function hrefPage()
{
    var pagina = "index.php?id=renew";
    location.href = pagina;
}

function loadArray(value)
{
    element_selected[i] = value;
    i++;
}

</script>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    if ($_GET['id'] == "renew")
    {
        $selected_elements = array();
        $j = 0;
        for($j = 0; $j < "<script> document.write(i) </script>"; $j++)
        {
            $selected_elements[j] = "<script> document.write(elements_selected[j]) </script>";
            echo $selected_elements[j];
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: PHP is executed first on the server. Aftwerwards JS in executed in your browser. Therefore you cannot use JS in your PHP code as you do in your for loop

Comment: You cannot write JavaScript in the middle of PHP like that, it won't be interpreted. To PHP those are just strings. You also should avoid `document.write` altogether.

Comment: Where are you calling hrefpage() method

Comment: @Aparna Hi, sorry, I forgot this: <?php echo '<form name="formHref" action="" method="post">';
 echo '<input type="button" value="href" class="buttonhref" onclick="hrefPage()" style="margin-left:600px;"/>'; echo '</form>'; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use local storage to use retain javascript variables value across page reloads

```
        var varName = "sachin";
        localStorage.setItem("varName", VarName);

        alert(localStorage.getItem("varName"));
```

Another example how to store array in localstorage

```
var arrayName= [];
arrayName[0] = prompt("Enter your value");
localStorage.setItem("arrayName", JSON.stringify(arrayName));

//...
var storedValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arrayName"));
```

I have added a simple example here how to set javascript value in localstorage and how to access it

I have provided it as an information for you to retain value across page reloads 
but first thing about http is that it is a stateless protocol .Each request fetches data from server and renders it in browser the value here is set in local storage of browser .So if you want to reload some value to script after page reload you need to set some flags and on page load check that flag if flag condition for the required situation arises get data from localstorage else proceed as normal

[Check out this tutorial for more information](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)